# How to hide the edit button form based on state field of invoice Odoo v8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to hide the edit button when a invoice' state is paid, just like the image below.

[image]

And I was inheriting the **invoice_form** and add the corresponding attribute.

```
<record id="invoice_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">invoice.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expt='//form[@string="Invoice"]' possition='attributes'>

            <!-- Frist intent : nothing happened -->
            <attribute name="edit" attrs="{'invisible:[('state','=','paid')]'}"/>

            <!-- Second intent : edit, always hide -->
            <attribute name="edit" attrs="{'invisible:[('state','=','paid')]'}">false</field>

            <!-- Thirds intent : edit, never hide -->
            <attribute name="edit" attrs="{'invisible:[('state','=','paid')]'}">true</field>
    </field>
```

Please help me, what it's wrong? Thanks!!

**EDIT**

Following the recomendations of @Sathiyan, I created a `/security/invoice_security.xml` file and add in my `__opnenerp__.py`, inside I added this lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="rule_no_edit_invoice_paid" model="ir.rule">
            <field name="name">rule.no.edit.invoice.paid</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="account.model_account_invoice"/>
            <field name="group" eval="[(4,ref('account.group_account_invoice'))]"/>
            <field name="domain_force">[('state','=','paid')]</field>
            <field eval="1" name="perm_read"/>
            <!--
            <field eval="0" name="perm_create"/>
            <field eval="0" name="perm_write"/>
            <field eval="0" name="perm_unlink"/>
            -->
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

As I put `noupdate="1"` I created a new database and installed it there, but nothing is happened! Can you tell me what I doing wrong? please.

Comment: why do you want to hide the edit button ?

Comment: @m3asmi An Invoice in paid state can not be edited for security reasons

Comment: add atribute to the fields you don't want to be edited with state is paid

Comment: same requirement for me also, in Leads, if not own leads should be Read only. One thing, <attribute name="edit">0</attribute> is going to Hide the Edit button . SO, i think no need to send invisible and all, some thing else we have to do.

Comment: You can handle it from .py, overriding the write function and checking the state when trying to do a write

Comment: checkout my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663748/odoo-disabled-edit-button-depending-on-state

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing fields through inheritance and adding **attrs** to it. Using attrs, you can set the field invisible when state is paid like this,

```
        <field name="edit" attrs="{'invisible':[('state', '=', 'paid')]}"/>
```

Comment: "edit" it's not a field! even if you change 'field' for 'button', by xpath I got `<xpath expr="//field[@name='edit']" > can not be located in parent view`, by the traditional form I got `<field name="edit"> can not be located in parent view`, like I said the error using field or button its the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add a **Record Rule** for **account.invoice** object with Read permission alone. And a domain filter as `[('state','=','paid')]`.

Comment: I've been trying add a Record Rule like the code above in my current **Edit**, but nothing are changing, please check it out, and tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: First try to add the record rules through the application. And use the above domain as suggested. If you want this to apply all user, leave the group as it is(empty), it'll make the record rule as global.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding `load_record` of `FormView` widget:

```js
openerp.module_name = function(instance, local) {
    var instance = openerp;
    var FormView = instance.web.FormView;

    // override load_record
    FormView.include({
        load_record: function(record) {
        // disable only for purchase.order
        if (record){
            // allow this behavior only for purchase.order  
            if (this.model == 'purchase.order' & _.contains(['done', 'cancel'], record.state)){
                    $('button.oe_form_button_edit').hide()
                }else {
                    $('button.oe_form_button_edit').show()
                }
        }
        // call super
        return this._super(record);
        }
    });
}
```

Check this `app` if you looking for full code:

[Disable edit button for paid invoice](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/disable_edit_don_invoice/)