# Which method is called, when User click on "Edit Button"?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have tried with *write*, but I was wrong, this method is not invoked. I really need to check nobody be able to edit an invoice form when its `status is paid`, so I want to override the method who is called when "Edit Button" is clicked.

**Edit: to clarify my question **

[image]

The button in the red square, its the button what I want override(or in the best of the cases 'hide') to don't let anybody edit the form when the invoice' state is paid!

Answer (score 2):

When you click on *"Edit Button"* after click on *save* button, it's always call *write* method of that object. Other than their is no specific method available.

In Odoo/OpenERP, Invoice is confirm or paid, no one can edit it's details. Some constraints are set on it. But if you want to edit details in any states than you need to modify fields definition.

Let's take an example:

*account_invoice.py*

```
'name': fields.char('Description', size=64, select=True, readonly=True, states={'draft':[('readonly',False)]}),
```

Here is some attributes effect explanation:

- readonly=True, => this will set constraint with readonly. No one can edit it from the GUI in all states of object.
- states={'draft':[('readonly',False)]} => this means, field with draft state, user can edit it.

Now in your case:

You need to make a custom module and override the .py side fields declaration like need to remove *readonly = True*

If you want to prevent edit for specific state than give it state with *states={'state_name':[('readonly',False)]}*

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr. @Odedra I think you don't understood me, the "Edit Button" is Odoo's button, it always appears on the top of the form, I'm going to edit mi question to show an image.

Comment: Let me update my answer. yes after edit button, you must to save record to see the updated record. You can play with write method. Other than on Edit button their is no method will call.

Comment: Thanks Mr. @Odedra, I'm going to try override _write_ method in a better way, please check my other question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014443/how-to-hide-the-edit-button-form-only-when-invoice-state-is-paid-odoo-v8) It's the same topic. Thanks for your time, my best wishes for you!

Answer (score 2):

by clicking on edit button, no method will be called. After clicking on edit and accessing any field,  **while clicking on save button then write method will be called [*** note that if we access any field then only, it will be called]**.

When you click on create button and fill the form then save button, **then create method will be called.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer @shravan , I have tried to override the _write_ method too, but in the line to become a sale oder/quotation in an invoice, the _write_ method is called more than one time, thats why I can't put an exception/raise to don't write if the state is not paid. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

> I really need to check nobody be able to edit an invoice form when its status is `paid`

In that case, check the `state` field, and if it is `paid`, make all the fields read only.

May sound like an insane idea; but that seems to be the solution

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr. @aliasm2k I think you don't understood me, the "Edit Button" is Odoo's button, it always appears on the top of the form, I'm going to edit mi question to show an image.

Comment: I understood you @JuanSalcedo I don't think there is any function you can override to include any functions while clicking the `Edit` button. So, I am sticking with my solution.

Comment: After read and try a lot, I can say with totally security, there isn't a method in charge to the edit button, I inherited the template and renamed the button, but I can't change it's functionality depending to an invoice' state, anyway Thanks a lot for your time! my best wishes for you!

Answer (score 0):

On edit no method is called but when you save the write method is called and check the link [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html) to get the details of methods on save.

Comment: your answer does not help in anyway, it's the same to suggest I need search in google, have a nice day sr