# Odoo disabled edit button depending on state

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

this question already asked by someone, this in an example question

[How to hide the edit button form only when invoice' state is 'paid' Odoo v8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014443/how-to-hide-the-edit-button-form-only-when-invoice-state-is-paid-odoo-v8)

but i dont get true answer, somebody can help me, i really need to hide or disabled this button.

For your information im using odoo v.10

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think odoo allows you to hide edit button depending state

Comment: See sale order...

Comment: You can costumise a field by state

Comment: You can not hide Edit button based on the state. Instead you can make the fields readonly

Comment: Yes, `attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('invoice_status', '!=', 'no'), ('state', '!=', 'sale')]}`

Comment: is readonly can be based on state? @sfx

Comment: What should i do with that code, in sale_view,xml the module create button then give attrs, should me create the button also ?

Comment: No, this is an example, how to hide field based on state

Comment: I know about that things, but how to set edit = False in Form based on state ? Im sorry for my little knowledge in odoo :v

Comment: Readonly can be changed based on the state using attrs

Comment: @KodeKite  I marked you question in my bookmark a while a go in order to help you but I forget about it sorry for taking this long to answer. I struggled with this problem before and this how I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to this is by `Javascript` you need to add this behavior to your form view
build a custom addon  and just add this javascript file to your `backend assets template`

```js
//file: static/src/js/disable_edit_for_paid_invoice.js

openerp.your_addon_name = function(instance, local) {
    var instance = openerp;
    var FormView = instance.web.FormView;

    // override load_record
    FormView.include({
        load_record: function(record) {
        // disable only for cancel and paid account.invoice
        if (record){
            if (this.model == 'account.invoice' & _.contains(['paid', 'cancel'], record.state)){
                    $('button.oe_form_button_edit').hide()
                }else {
                    $('button.oe_form_button_edit').show()
                }
        }
        // call super
        return this._super(record);
        }
    });
}
```

Add this to backend asset template

```xml
    <template id="assets_backend" name="disable edit paid invoice assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/your_addon_name/static/src/js/disable_edit_for_paid_invoice.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
```

Don't forget to replace `your_addon_name` by the `real addon name that you create`.

Comment: This solution if for version 8.0 only but it's easy to make it work in other version wil small changes